# Restricting keys to elements that have specified attribute set

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I want to be able to reference specific xml elements from other. To do so this element has an optional Attribute `name`.

To validate that all references exist U use the elements `key` and `keyref` in the xsd.

The key definition looks something like this:

```
<key name="LevelPK">
  <selector xpath='./test:Level'/>
  <field xpath="@Name"/>
</key>
```

The keyref

```
<keyref name="LevelFK" refer="test:LevelPK">
  <selector xpath=".//test:LevelRequirement/test:Level"/>
  <field xpath="@Name"/>
</keyref>
```

The problem is that the Name Attribute is optional for the keys. I want only to create them if I have to reference them on another element.

This results in an error that the field Name can not be found for those by the key. As far as I understand xPath, I should be able to define a query that looks for every element with specific attributes. `xpath="./test:Level[@Name]"` But now I get an error that the xpath is not valid for this element.

I use VS2017 for validation.